# Will Apache check a RewriteRule on every request if the REQUEST_URI is not explicitly set in a RewriteCond?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm pretty new to Apache Rewrites, so this is probably a simple question (that is not so simple to find direct answers to).

So I have the following Rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^parm=([a-z]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^path/to/some_script.php /simple-url-$1.html? [R=301,L]
```

Which appears to function as expected in testing:

```
www.mydomain.com/path/to/some/script.php?parm=foo
```

correctly 301's to:

```
www.mydomain.com/simple-url-foo.html
```

However, my concern is that without a RewriteCond explicitly defining the script, that this condition will get checked on every request, regardless if it's for some_script.php... leading to an unnecessary load on Apache.

Is this the case?  If so, I'm having trouble figuring out how to use the REQUEST_URI in this case, IE:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^path/to/some_script.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^parm=([a-z]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^path/to/some_script.php /simple-url-$1.html? [R=301,L]
```

The above does not seem to work, and I'm not sure why.  Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, the `%{REQUEST_URI}` condition is unnecessary.

By adding the condition, you're just moving the request URI comparison to happen before the query string. It's still going to be compared with every request that comes. In fact, this makes the situation worse now because the comparison for `some_script.php` would happen twice. Once in the `RewriteCond` and one more time in the `RewriteRule`.

And, with your original setup, it's not like every request URI is being checked for `some_script.php`. The `%{QUERY_SRING}` also makes sure that the comparison happens for only those requests that came with `parm` query parameter.

Comment: Sure boss I will provide my answer in few minutes after analyzing it.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal Thank you greatly for the pointers!  With what you said in mind, is there a way to improve the Rewrite to only evaluate this rule when the "parm" parameter is paired with some_script.php?  In case there are other scripts/pages which have similarly named parameters?

Comment: @JR.XYZA, that's exactly what's happenning. `%{QUERY_STRING}` first checks if a `parm` is present or not and **if** yes then checks if the file requested is `some_script.php` or not. Those are the only two checks required to fire the rule. **No more, no less.**